# How i can use Vue module in SSR WITHOUT Nuxt.js with native vue-server-renderer module?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js, single-page-application, server-side-rendering

I have a problem, I cannot use SSR from the official documentation https://ssr.vuejs.org/ in any way, I could not include any module using the native way of creating SSR. I always get an error `window is not defined` even if the module has adaptations for SSR. Why is **vue-server-renderer** not working?! Why should I definitely use **Nuxt.js**?

**My project use vue v2.x and webpack v4.x.x, because SSR modules with Vue2 is not working with webpack version 5.x.x, but I guess that's not the reason**

For example i use **vue-js-modal** module, which having ssr include files, but it is not working, if i include it with code

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VModal from 'vue-js-modal/dist/ssr.nocss'
import 'vue-js-modal/dist/styles.css'
Vue.use(VModal, { ... })
```

I getting this errors

````
  vue-ssr-server-bundle.json

Compilation Time: 749.594ms
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Module.o.m.n (/var/www/contest.mathzilla.org/public_html/frontend/node_modules/vue-js-modal/dist/ssr.nocss.js:1:14289)
    at o (/var/www/contest.mathzilla.org/public_html/frontend/node_modules/vue-js-modal/dist/ssr.nocss.js:1:32717)```
````